# HTML input element being clipped by parent container

Tags: html, css, alignment

A picture says a thousand words:

[image]

Do you see the search box on the left? The parent is hiding a portion of the bottom of the search box. The alignment is off, and I can't figure out why. The effect is persistent in both Chrome and Firefox.

Take a look at this Chrome debugger snapshot:

[image]

So the parent container (blue) is one of three equal width div containers spanning that "header" section you're looking at (which is also a div). Now, I've also tried to solve this laying out the divs in a table format using "display: table", as well as using an actual table layout. Both of these result in the same problem, except that instead of hiding the unseen portion of the search box, the box is fully visible. It's still out of alignment with the button to it's left though. But it doesn't extend the parent container height to accommodate it, it floats out and hovers over the small top-margin belonging to the main content box below.

Playing with the margin of the search box has no effect, it won't budge. I should also mention that this only happens with an input element. If I switch to a textarea, it's working as it should, aligned properly (I'm reluctant to just use one, I don't want a multi-line textbox). Also, in this example here, I'm floating the first two "header" containers from the left (search and navigation button containers) while the last container (with 1/35) on the right has overflow: hidden to make it fill out the rest of the available width (the overall "header" container also has overflow: hidden to make this trick work). Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="gallery-controls" class="gallery-height">

    <div id="gallery-controls-search" class="gallery-height">
        <div id="gallery-search-button"></div>
        <input id="gallery-search-box" placeholder="Search..." />
    </div>

    <div id="gallery-controls-navigation" class="gallery-height">
        <div id="prev-gallery-button" class="gallery-navigation-button"></div>
        <div id="next-gallery-button" class="gallery-navigation-button"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="gallery-controls-info" class="gallery-height">
        <span id="navigation-position-info">1/35</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#gallery-controls {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 8px 0px 0px 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery-height {
    height: 55px;
}

/**************** SEARCH ****************/
#gallery-controls-search {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    text-align: left;
}
#gallery-search-button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background: url(/static/images/search-button.png);
    cursor: pointer;
}
#gallery-search-box {
    display: inline-block;  
    font-family: "BebasNeueRegular";
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #DDDDDD;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;

    background: #222222; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #666;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #666;

    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);

    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

/**************** NAVIGATION ****************/
#gallery-controls-navigation {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    text-align: center;
}
.gallery-navigation-button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#prev-gallery-button {
    background: url(/static/images/prev-gallery-button.png);
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#next-gallery-button {
    background: url(/static/images/next-gallery-button.png);
}

/**************** INFO ****************/
#gallery-controls-info {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#navigation-position-info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8px;
    right: 3px;
    font-family: "Lane-Narrow";
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #222;
}
```

Can anyone offer any insight or suggest why this is happening?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or link?

Answer (score 0):

give "gallery-search-box" a margin value:

```
#gallery-search-box {
margin:10px;
}
```

Comment: Nothing, it doesn't budge at all for any margin values.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.gallery-height {
  height: 55px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. The float solution posted by @GEspinha or my own absolute positioning solution will do the trick though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the button is interfering with the search input field because you are compressing two elements in one div. You should float both to the left and add a clear:both div as a third child as such:

HTML

```
<div id="gallery-controls-search" class="gallery-height">
    <div id="gallery-search-button"></div>
    <input id="gallery-search-box" placeholder="Search..." />
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#gallery-search-button, #gallery-search-box {
    float:left;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

Try that ;)

Answer (score 0):

After all that, I got it working using absolute positioning e.g.

```
position: relative;
```

...for the parent container of the search box, and:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

...for the search box. Thanks anyway to everyone.